# Can I interact with Rails models within a Capistrano task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano

I often used Rake tasks that are dependent upon the Rails environment task having loaded.  I then interact with Rails Models within the Rake tasks.  Can I do this in Capistrano?

Answer (score 1):

You can definately use capistrano to fire a rake task.

```
  desc 'Run a Rake Task.'
  task :after_deploy, :roles => :app do
    run "cd /path/to/app && rake -e environnment task here"
  end
```

If you are asking if you can access a rails model from Capistrano, then I would say I don't think so unless you are using some other way that also loads a rails environment, like script/runner.

I'd say stick with firing a rake task from Capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

The below might be better:

```
run "cd #{current_path} && #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} sunspot:solr:stop"
```